# I don't understand function calls function

Tags: python, function

Write a function called printx() that just prints the letter "x". Then write a function called multiplex() which takes as argument an integer and prints as many times the letter "x" as the integer indicates by calling the function printx() that many times. Can someone help me with this exercise?

I wrote:

```
def printx():
    print("x")

def multiplex(a):
    return a * printx

print(multiplex(5))
```

but it doesn't work because I can't multiply int and function.

Comment: Are you para-phrasing the problem statement? Otherwise, it's a bad description

Answer (score 4):

`printx` function should return the `x` as string

```
def printx():
    return "x"


def multiplex(a):
    return a * printx()


print(multiplex(5))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
xxxxx
```